# Replace ** enclosed text with b tag

Tags: python, regex

I have a string.

```
"This is an ** example ** sentence. It is ** awesome **."
```

I want to replace all instances of `**.**` with `<b>.</b>` preserving the wildcard text matched by `.`

The result should be:

```
"This is an <b>example</b> sentence. It is <b>awesome</b>."
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What have you already tried and what exactly do you need help with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a capturing group `()` to match text enclosed by `**` on either side (you have to escape them in the regex with like `\*`, because they're regex control characters otherwise). Then, you can refer to the captured group in the replacement text using `\1`:

```
import re
inp = "This is an **example** sentence. It is **awesome**."
out = re.sub(r'\*\*(.+?)\*\*', r'<b>\1</b>', inp)
# 'This is an <b>example</b> sentence. It is <b>awesome</b>.'
```

---

If you want to do more complicated things to the group you just isolated, then you can give a lambda or a function as the second argument to `re.sub()`. For example, to make the captured group uppercase:

```
out = re.sub(r'\*\*([^*]+)\*\*', 
             lambda g: f'<b>{g.group(1).upper()}</b>', 
             inp)
# 'This is an <b>EXAMPLE</b> sentence. It is <b>AWESOME</b>.'
```

The lambda function is called with a regex result object,  so `g.group(1)` is the equivalent to `\1`, i.e. the first captured group in the pattern. As a string, of course. We just call `.upper()` on it to make it uppercase.

Comment: Cloak
How do we make capitalize after replacing only such block which is enclosed in between ** **?

Comment: @RajeevUppala You can give a lambda function instead of just the string `r'<b>\1</b>`, which can do more complicated things, e.g. `lambda g: f'<b>{g.group(1).upper()}</b>'`. I've edited this into my answer.